# why is needed add appearances aliases to widgets build by _createChildControlImpl()?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm creating some UI compose by a TabView inside another TabView.
To the insider TabView I add a specific tab, all via `_createChildControlImpl()` implementation,

some like

```
qx.Class.define('rigel.view.Dashboard', {
    extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

    construct: function(layout) {
        this.base(arguments, layout);
        this.add(this.getChildControl("container"), {edge: 'center'});
    },

    // overridden
    _createChildControlImpl: function(id, hash) {
        var control;

        switch (id) {
            case "container":
                control = new my.view.tabview.ResourcesCat();
                break;
...
```

and

```
qx.Class.define('my.view.tabview.ResourcesCat', {
    extend: qx.ui.tabview.TabView,

    _createChildControlImpl: function(id, hash) {
        var control;

        switch(id) {
            case "static":
                control = new qx.ui.tabview.Page('', 'icon.png');
                this.add(control);
```

I do this for set that TabPage only in some cases.

Anyway, I do not understand why for each widget buil by `_createChildControlImpl` I have to add aliases to Appearance if I do not want change any of theme.

So I have

```
"widget/tabview": "tabview",
"tabview/static": "tabview-page",
"tabview/static/tab-name": "tabview-page",
```

I will prefer some way to avoid add appareance aliases for each widget, and keep the construction inside of `_createChildControlImpl`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_createChildControlImpl is designed for UI components which form part of the main widget - for example, TabView has child controls which are the button bar and the composite for holding the pages; a Page has a button for the tab; a button has a child control for an icon and another for the label; and so on

For all of those "child controls", their styling is often very much part of the styling of the parent *widget* which is why Appearances support paths like "button/icon" or "button/label".

This can be slightly confusing because a "child control" is just another widget, but its important to keep the distinction especially when it comes to theming.

In  your example, the "static" and "container" widgets should not be instantiated as child controls at all - for example, you could initialise them as member variables inside a constructor:

```
qx.Class.define('rigel.view.Dashboard', {
    extend: qx.ui.container.Composite,

    construct: function(layout) {
        this.base(arguments, layout);
        this.__container = new my.view.tabview.ResourcesCat();
        this.add(this.__container, {edge: 'center'});
    },
```

and

```
qx.Class.define('my.view.tabview.ResourcesCat', {
    extend: qx.ui.tabview.TabView,

    construct: function() {
        this.base(arguments);
        this.__static = new qx.ui.tabview.Page('', 'icon.png');
        this.add(this.__static);
    }
```